# Get text of .strings file

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, localizable.strings

I am trying to display the text of a `.strings` file in a `UITextView`. This is my code:

```
self.textview.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:self.txtPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

but it appears that the encoding is wrong, because every time I the `UITextView` is blank, no text is in it. But it works with `.txt`, `.log` and other files. So how can I get the text of a `.strings` file?

[image]

Comment: how are u getting txtPath? post the code for it

Comment: To debug separate the steps. First get the file contents into a `NSString` and `NSLog` it. The second second step assign the string to the textview. This way you can divide the problem. In this case you will see that the string is not obtained because the encoding is incorrect. See the answer by @maddy.

Comment: @Zaph I can get the file content of any other file, but not of .strings. its with this file format.

Comment: The point is "How to Debug": Breakup compound statements. In this case the question becomes simpler: "Reading the strings file is failing." In fact shy away from compound statements when writing code and rely on the compiler to remove them on the release build. Optimize nothing unless/until there are performance issues and then use the profiler to find the exact things that need to be improved. Write for readability and simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

The `.strings` files tend to be created with the `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding` encoding, not UTF-8.

BTW - you can easily see the encoding of any file in your Xcode project. Bring up the right pane in Xcode. Then select a file in the project tree. In the right pane, look for the "Text Settings" section. It has a "Text Encoding" entry.

One other thing. Make it easier to solve such a problem. Break up the code for easier debugging and use the `error`parameter.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *text = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentOfFile:self.txtPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (text) {
    self.textview.text = text;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Unable to load text from %@: %@", self.txtPath, error);
}
```

Comment: The .string files in my project are encoded with NSUTF8StringEncoding, but NSUTF8StringEncoding didnt work. I also tryed it with NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding like you sayed, but I get a lot of chinese (An image is in the original post) Is there a way to detect the the encoding? There is no error when I use NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding.

Comment: This is the error I get: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x1782665c0 {NSFilePath=/Applications/AdSheet.app/French.lproj/Localizable.strings, NSStringEncoding=4}

Comment: That error seems to verify that the file is not in UTF-8 format. What text encoding is shown in the right pane of Xcode for this strings file?

Comment: i dont know, the file isnt in my xcode project, its in "/Applications/AdSheet.app/French.lproj/Localizable.strings", the file is in the AdSheet app.

Comment: Open a terminal (iTerm) on your computer. Enter `cd /Applications/AdSheet.app/French.lproj`. Then enter `file Localizable.strings`. What is the result?

Comment: This is on my iDevice, and why should I cd in the directory? The file is there, I am 100% sure, I can see it.

Comment: I didn't know it was on your iDevice. I'm trying to help you determine the file's encoding so you can get this working.

Comment: OK, but I cant do this for every .strings file, but I am building a filebrowser, so There must be a way to view the file.

Comment: Read the file with `NSData`, dump that and post the first 100 bytes of the NSLog of the `NSData`. Then we have a change of figuring out what is happening. Why do you thing it is UTD8 encoded? Also, is this a JailBreak app, I'm wondering because it seems you are trying to read data from another app.